# How to call onDraw after setContentView(R.layout.main)?

Tags: android

I have something to draw at runtime. I did drawing in onDraw in MyView class.
Because, I already used  setContentView(R.layout.main) in onCreate, I cannot use it again.
How to call onDraw after setContentView(R.layout.main)?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); // I have something to draw in XML also.
        MyView myView = new MyView(this);
        // setContentView(myView); I cannot use setContentView two times.
}
protected class MyView extends View {
    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
           // there are some drawing codes and these cannot be done in XML.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two ways

1:
You could add your myView (instance) to an ViewGroup defined in R.layout.main

2:
You could directly add use MyView in your XML R.layout.main.
Instead of "LinearLayout" and so on, you the full qualified class name

see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html (at bottom)

Comment: I have not tried yet. But i think it will work. It is just like using custom widget.

Answer (score 1):

You should not call onDraw() yourself. Instead, to force a redraw, call [`invalidate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29).

> If the view is visible, `onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)` will be
>   called at some point in the future.

Comment: I called myView.invalidate(); after setContentView(R.layout.main); in onCreate. It does not work. Where do I call invalidate?

Comment: I guess you've not added your view to the activity. The activity can not display a view unless it's added to the view hierarchy. Depending on your requirement, you may need to add it to a particular layout in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

    MakeView makeView = new MakeView(this);

    relativeLayout.addView(makeView);
    relativeLayout.invalidate();
}
```

I noticed that onDraw was called after addView.